# Java doesn't recognize my unicode emoji (error: unknown emoji)

Tags: java, string, discord, discord4j

I have a problem with Strings and Unicode in Java.
I'm currently working on a bot for Discord and have to pass it a string with an emoji. For this I use the java-specific form, i.e. I want to have the emoji "fire", for example. If I manually set my method for java-specific code (\uD83D \uDD25) in a string, it works, but if I use the return value (also a string) there, the whole thing no longer works.
Hence the question of whether it makes a difference if the java-specific code is entered manually and if it is entered automatically. Maybe java can't recognize that the second one is also an unicode?

Thanks for your help

```
String emoji1 = "\uD83D\uDD25";
String emoji2 = convertToJava(":fire:"); //return a String with the content "\uD83D\uDD25"

msg.addReaction(ReactionEmoji.of(id, emoji1, isAnimated)).block(); //this is working
msg.addReaction(ReactionEmoji.of(id, emoji2, isAnimated)).block(); //this returns me an error called "unknown emoji"
```

Comment: Why should it make a difference?

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't make sense to me. And yet I get the error, although the same string would have to be passed in both cases.

Comment: What error do you get? What makes you sure it is the same?

Comment: I am getting an unknown emoji error from discord4J. My return value is the same as the one stored in emoji1. However, java does not recognize this as unicode, which is likely to lead to this error. Unfortunately, I don't know how I can modify this return value so that java also recognizes it as unicode.

Comment: Full java class:
[link](https://pastebin.com/sTkdNEF8)

Comment: Can you show both unicode strings in a debugger? Is their length and hashCode the same?

Comment: Okay, it has been confirmed that they are not identical. The values are as follows:
emoji1 | Hashcode: 1772680 | Length: 2 | Debug value: ߔ¥ |||
emoji2 | Hashcode: -2056673190 | Length: 12 | Debug value: \\uD83D\\uDD25

Comment: The first one contains the actual emoji wgile the second one escapes the emoji (the `\uD838` are all seperate characters in the second one). This is why the second one doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that too. What exactly can I do to display the second string like the first?